# How do I use Linux Mint and ffmpeg software to stabilize a large video?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video

I made a video with `openshot` that is 7.3 GB. `ffmpeg` only stabilizes half the video. Is there a length limit of `ffmpeg` that is used? This is what I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf vidstabtransform,unsharp=5:5:0.8:3:3:0.4 out_stabilized.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe FFmpeg will be hitting any duration limit in 7.3GiB worth of video.

It may be there is an error in your video, command, or some sort of resource starvation.

Here are some things you can do to try to narrow down the problem.

1. Try to stabilize the video in two parts and append them together later to work around the problem with the following command.

   ```
   ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30 -i input -vf vidstabdetect -f null - && ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30 -i input -vf vidstabtransform,unsharp=5:5:0.8:3:3:0.4 out_stabilized-1.mkv && ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -to 00:01:00 -i input -vf vidstabdetect -f null - && ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -to 00:01:00 -i input -vf vidstabtransform,unsharp=5:5:0.8:3:3:0.4 out_stabilized-2.mkv
   ```

   This example runs detection, creates the transform for the start of the video to 30 seconds in and then runs the stabilizer. If both of those succeed it repeats the commands for 30 seconds in to 1 minute in.

   Change the times of `-ss 00:00:00` and`-to 00:00:00` to the start, and the point immediately before the stabilizing fails, respectively, for the first set of commands. For the second set change the times to immediately after your cut point in the first command and the end of your video. Omitting `-to` in the second set may work, too.

   This will be much more accurate if you can cut to exact frames with a little math and the format `00:00:00.00 (HH:MM:SS.MS)`. Merging can be done in FFmpeg or with a couple clicks in [mkvmerge](https://mkvtoolnix.download/downloads.html) (recommended).
2. Again, try to stabilize the video in two parts and merge them later, this time cutting with [Avidemux](https://avidemux.sourceforge.net/download.html). This will let you easily select a keyframe. You can expirement by cutting just a snip of video from a keyframe a few seconds before the failure point and a few seconds after it, saving, and trying to stabilize it.

   If it succeeds, there probably isn't an error in the video in the cause is likely elsewhere.

   You can now try selecting a keyframe directly before the failure with the B marker and save the selection. Now select this keyframe again with the A marker and jump to the end of the video and save selection again. Attempt to stabilize both parts in FFmpeg and append.